# Required Associated Entity Causing Validation Errors

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have something like the following:

```
public class EntityA
{
    [Required]
    long? EntityBId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EntityBId ")]
    public virtual EntityB { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB
{
    [Key]
    long EntityBId { get; set; }
}
```

When I go to use it as follows I get a validation error because required property `EntityBId` is null.

```
EntityA a = new EntityA();
a.EntityB = new EntityB();
dbContext.EntityAs.Add(EntityA);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

However if I remove the `[Required]` attribute then both `EntityA` and `EntityB` get added to the database and `EntityBId` gets populated by the `SaveChanges` call.

How can I mark `EntityBId` as `[Required]` and avoid entity framework validation from failing?

Comment: Why do you need to mark it as `[Required]` if you don't need it to be required?

Comment: @Alexander it is required

Answer (score 0):

See this link for usage of Required annotation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-annotations -

> "The Required annotation tells EF that a particular property is
>   required.
>
> Adding Required to the Title property will force EF (and MVC) to
>   ensure that the property has data in it."

so you have to decide, if you want [Required] annotation then it means it will not allow nullable property. And if you are okay with null value then remove [Required] annotation.

Comment: The property should not be null.  It is the ID of a required associated entity.  The association is established through the assignment of an instance to the virtual property for the associated entity.  The entity framework then populates the ID on its side during the call to SaveChanges.  Which it does if it gets passed its own validation.

Comment: if you change it from nullable<long>(long?) to long, it will set it to 0 by default and EF automatically assigns proper id on save.

Comment: Maybe, not sure if that will provide the desired behavior.  I'll have to test.  The issue could be that 0 is a valid value pointing to a separate record.  I'm not sure how entity framework would know if it is support to point to record 0 or assign the value from a new record being inserted.

Comment: @denver -  When you will set navigation property (virtual property) to instance EF will set foreign key correctly to the id created for the referenced record. Try it.

Comment: Tested it, per my last comment if you set the id to 0 entity framework has an issue and throws an exception.  This does not surprise me because entity framework is being supplied with conflicting information.  I assume because the foreign key has an id implying it is already in the database while the navigation property (virtual property) instance is not and does not have an id.

Comment: Per the comment about the foreign key being set correctly, it is not when the id is marked as required, that is why I asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

There can be two scenarios:

**First:** `EntityB` already existed in the database and you are pointing the `EntityBId` of the `EntityB` to the `EntityBId` `ForeignKey` of the new `EntityA` as follows and in this case only `EntityA` will be inserted to the database:

```
EntityB entityB = dbContext.EntityBs.FirstOrDefault(yourCondition) 

EntityA entityA = new EntityA();
entityA.EntityBId = entityB.EntityBId; // <-- assign `ForeignKey` value instead of navigation property value, hence no required validation error will occur

dbContext.EntityAs.Add(entityA);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

**Second:** `EntityB` is not already existed in the database and it will be newly inserted to the database along with `EntityA`. So in this case your code should be as follows:

```
EntityB entityB = new EntityB();
dbContext.EntityBs.Add(entityB);

EntityA entityA = new EntityA();
entityA.EntityBId = entityB.EntityBId; // <-- assign `ForeignKey` value instead of navigation property value, hence no required validation error will occur
dbContext.EntityAs.Add(entityA);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Now decide what is your scenario and do accordingly.

Comment: The second situation is in play.  The code you provide will not work because entityB.EntityBId is null until the call to SaveChanges.

Comment: @denver `The code you provide will not work because entityB.EntityBId is null `- No! it will work. EF  is smart enough to maintain this during insert.

Comment: Try your code.  You are setting entityA.EntityBId = null (this line does nothing).  Validation will then fail because EntityBId is marked required.  If EntityBId was not marked required entity framework would establish the relationship during insert.

Comment: @denver Is not `EntityBId` a auto incremented primary key?

Comment: EntityBId is the primary key, I believe it is auto incremented by default.

Comment: @denver Then I am 100% sure it will work if you can implement as I have said.

Comment: I have tried your code.  It does not work. entityB.EntityBId is not assigned until the call to SaveChanges, hence it is not available to use before that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190929/discussion-between-tanvirarjel-and-denver).